# Проброс внешнего адреса Docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

День добрый. Есть контейнер Wireguard, в нём подключено сетевое оборудование на мониторинг в Prometheus. При попытке подключиться из snmp_exporter к IP 10.13.13.4 - timeout. Само оборудование доступно, из контейнера Wireguard пингуется, но с других ни в какую. Сетка вся объединена в:

```
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

[image: Скрин]

Что нужно: мне необходимо пробросить IP подсетки Wireguard внутрь хоста(подсеть 10.13.13.0/24). Если есть вариант лучше - просьба помочь. Спасибо!